# AngularJS context menu to show closest next div only

Tags: angularjs

How to show the context menu related `div` on my on click function? How to find the closest next `div` class and make visible on click on the button event, instead of showing all the `div` having the same classes.

Please note below my HTML and js also the fiddle link for reference:
    http://jsfiddle.net/4WK7R/274/

**HTML:**

```
        <div ng-app>
            <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                <div class="row">
                  <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert()">Click me</button>
                  <div ng-show="myvalue" class="ng-cloak">11111111</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert()">Click me</button>
                  <div ng-show="myvalue" class="ng-cloak">22222222</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert()">Click me</button>
                  <div ng-show="myvalue" class="ng-cloak">333333333</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
    function MyCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.myvalue = false;

        $scope.showAlert = function(){
          $scope.myvalue = true;  
        };

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want i think:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row">
      <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert('div1')">Click me</button>
      <div ng-show="div1" class="ng-cloak">11111111</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert('div2')">Click me</button>
      <div ng-show="div2" class="ng-cloak">22222222</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="mybutton" ng-click="showAlert('div3')">Click me</button>
      <div ng-show="div3" class="ng-cloak">333333333</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.showAlert = function(show){
    //edited
    $scope[show] ? $scope[show] = false: $scope[show]= true; 
    //$scope[show] = true;  
  };
}
```

Comment: @Meher: thanks exactly it work fine. one more question on top of this, on click on any of body except the button also i want to hide the "ng-cloak" class any idea ? http://jsfiddle.net/4WK7R/279/

Comment: also only one context menu should open in all time, now if i keep open one menu and click on other "click me" two menu is appearing right? instead i want to close all other and only the recent clicked menu "ng-clok"  need to open - please suggest for this?

Comment: i think you want somthing like tabs.. checkout this answer

Answer (score 0):

Tabs:

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.tabs = [{
    title: "tab1",
    show: true
  }, {
    title: "tab2",
    show: false
  }, {
    title: "tab3",
    show: false
  }, ]
  $scope.tabAction = function(tab) {
    angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function(tab) {
      tab.show = false;
    });
    tab.show ? tab.show = false : tab.show = true;
  }
};
```

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
      <div ng-show="tab.show">{{tab.title}}</div>
      <button ng-hide="tab.show" ng-click="tabAction(tab)">
        open {{tab.title}}
      </button>
      <hr>
    </div>

  </div>
```